# Climate change impact / risk assessment

Tags: climate-change

I work for a local council in the UK. We want to include climate change as a mandatory consideration in all of our decision making. This would require project managers to look at the risk (what adaptation measures we need to consider) and impact (how the project would affect our emissions budget) of any large decisions.

I expect that this has been done before, but I can't find a guide or discussion of it anywhere. Please can you suggest sources of information / existing implementations?

Sorry if this isn't the most appropriate place to post this, if anybody knows of a more appropriate forum, I'd be happy to go there instead!

Comment: I think you goverment/appropriate ministry would have some guidelines on this? Maybe also ask some NGOs?

Comment: I found: https://ukcip.ouce.ox.ac.uk/wizard/future-climate-vulnerability/bacliat/

Comment: Regarding impacts, you want to have a lifecycle assesment of CO2 equivalent emissions.
Get in touch with Professor Mike Berners-Lee, he is surely interested in contributing to your project (he wrote the book "How bad are bananas?", where he estimates the emission impact of "everything".
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll do some more digging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UK Government already publishes information on this at the national level, which may be a useful guide for how to proceed at the local government level.

The last UK Climate Change Risk Assessment was [published in 2017](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-climate-change-risk-assessment-2017) and the next one is [imminent in mid-2021](https://www.ukclimaterisk.org/).  They follow risk assessment methods set out in things like the [HM Treasury Green Book](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/the-green-book-appraisal-and-evaluation-in-central-governent), which, despite the name, is not about environmental assessment specifically (there are Orange, Aqua and Magenta Books too).  The Green Book
has a shorter, [climate-specific supplement](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/green-book-supplementary-guidance-environment) that may be a good place to start.  In particular, Annex B of the supplement has lots of links to other resources and tools for doing the assessment.

There’s also a [local government website](https://www.local.gov.uk/our-support/climate-change/climate-action-council-plans) that hosts a slightly random selection of plans that various regions have put together over the last few years.

This all looks like a daunting amount of paperwork to a scientist like me, so good luck!